# Speeding up hexadoku in C (16 x 16 , a - p)

Tags: c, time, sudoku

i have serious problem with my hexadoku solver. I'd like to run the program under 2s but my solution solves it in cca 10s. Another problem is if the hexadoku has more then one solution, how i should just print the number of solutions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int isfree(int hexadoku[][16], int radek, int sloupec, int num)
{
    int rowStart = (radek/4) * 4;
    int colStart = (sloupec/4) * 4;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<16; ++i)
    {
        if (hexadoku[radek][i] == num)                           return 0;
        if (hexadoku[i][sloupec] == num)                         return 0;
        if (hexadoku[rowStart + (i%4)][colStart + (i/4)] == num) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int napln(int hexadoku[][16], int radek, int sloupec)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (sloupec >= 16)
    {
         sloupec = 0;
         ++radek;
         if (radek >= 16)
         {
             return 1;
         }
    }

     if( hexadoku[radek][sloupec] != 0)
        {
            return napln(hexadoku, radek, sloupec+1);
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=0; i<16; ++i)
            {
                if( isfree(hexadoku, radek, sloupec, i+1) )
                {
                    hexadoku[radek][sloupec] = i+1;

                    int good = napln(hexadoku, radek, sloupec +1);
                    if (good)
                    {   return 1;
                    }
                    hexadoku[radek][sloupec] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
}

int main()
{

    char pole[17][17];
    char tmp[66];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, m = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

    printf("Zadejte hexadoku:\n");
    while ( scanf( " %[^\n]", &tmp ) == 1 )
        {

            for ( j = 2; j <= 62; j += 4 )
            {
                if ( tmp[0] != '+' )
                    {
                        pole[i][k] = tmp[j];
                        k++;
                    }
            }

            pole[i][k] = '\0';
            k = 0;
            if ( tmp[0] != '+' )
            i++;
        }

    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
        {
            for ( l = 0; l < 16; l++ )
                {
                    if( !(( pole[i][l] >='a' && pole[i][l] <= 'p' ) || ( pole[i][l] == ' ' )) ) { printf("Nespravny vstup.\n"); return 1; }
                }
        }

    i = 0;
    l = 0;

    for (m = 0; m < 16; m++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < 16; l++)
            {
                if ((pole[m][l] == pole[m][i]) && (i != l) && (pole[m][l] != ' ') && (pole[m][i] != ' ') ) { printf("Nespravny vstup.\n"); return 1; }
                if ((pole[l][m] == pole[i][m]) && (i != l) && (pole[l][m] != ' ') && (pole[i][m] != ' ') ) { printf("Nespravny vstup.\n"); return 1; }
            }
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    l = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (l = 0; l < 16; l+=3)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                {
                    for (y = 0; y < 4; y++)
                    {
                       if(i==x && j==y) continue;
                       if ( (pole[i][j] == pole[x][y]) && (pole[i][j] != ' ') && (pole[x][y] != ' ') ) { printf("Nespravny vstup.\n"); return 1; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        i+=3;
        j+=3;
        x+=3;
        y+=3;
    }

    int hexadoku[16][16];


    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                switch (pole[i][j])
                {
                    case ' ': hexadoku[i][j]=0; break;
                    case 'a': hexadoku[i][j]=1; break;
                    case 'b': hexadoku[i][j]=2; break;
                    case 'c': hexadoku[i][j]=3; break;
                    case 'd': hexadoku[i][j]=4; break;
                    case 'e': hexadoku[i][j]=5; break;
                    case 'f': hexadoku[i][j]=6; break;
                    case 'g': hexadoku[i][j]=7; break;
                    case 'h': hexadoku[i][j]=8; break;
                    case 'i': hexadoku[i][j]=9; break;
                    case 'j': hexadoku[i][j]=10; break;
                    case 'k': hexadoku[i][j]=11; break;
                    case 'l': hexadoku[i][j]=12; break;
                    case 'm': hexadoku[i][j]=13; break;
                    case 'n': hexadoku[i][j]=14; break;
                    case 'o': hexadoku[i][j]=15; break;
                    case 'p': hexadoku[i][j]=16; break;
                    default : break;
                }
            }
        }

    if( napln(hexadoku, 0, 0) )
    {

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                switch (hexadoku[i][j])
                {
                    case 0: pole[i][j]= ' '; break;
                    case 1: pole[i][j]= 'a'; break;
                    case 2: pole[i][j]= 'b'; break;
                    case 3: pole[i][j]= 'c'; break;
                    case 4: pole[i][j]= 'd'; break;
                    case 5: pole[i][j]= 'e'; break;
                    case 6: pole[i][j]= 'f'; break;
                    case 7: pole[i][j]= 'g'; break;
                    case 8: pole[i][j]= 'h'; break;
                    case 9: pole[i][j]= 'i'; break;
                    case 10: pole[i][j]= 'j'; break;
                    case 11: pole[i][j]= 'k'; break;
                    case 12: pole[i][j]= 'l'; break;
                    case 13: pole[i][j]= 'm'; break;
                    case 14: pole[i][j]= 'n'; break;
                    case 15: pole[i][j]= 'o'; break;
                    case 16: pole[i][j]= 'p'; break;
                    default : break;
                }
            }
        }

        printf(
"+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
"| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
"+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"

, pole[0][0], pole[0][1], pole[0][2], pole[0][3], pole[0][4], pole[0][5], pole[0][6], pole[0][7], pole[0][8], pole[0][9], pole[0][10], pole[0][11], pole[0][12], pole[0][13], pole[0][14], pole[0][15]
, pole[1][0], pole[1][1], pole[1][2], pole[1][3], pole[1][4], pole[1][5], pole[1][6], pole[1][7], pole[1][8], pole[1][9], pole[1][10], pole[1][11], pole[1][12], pole[1][13], pole[1][14], pole[1][15]
, pole[2][0], pole[2][1], pole[2][2], pole[2][3], pole[2][4], pole[2][5], pole[2][6], pole[2][7], pole[2][8], pole[2][9], pole[2][10], pole[2][11], pole[2][12], pole[2][13], pole[2][14], pole[2][15]
, pole[3][0], pole[3][1], pole[3][2], pole[3][3], pole[3][4], pole[3][5], pole[3][6], pole[3][7], pole[3][8], pole[3][9], pole[3][10], pole[3][11], pole[3][12], pole[3][13], pole[3][14], pole[3][15]
, pole[4][0], pole[4][1], pole[4][2], pole[4][3], pole[4][4], pole[4][5], pole[4][6], pole[4][7], pole[4][8], pole[4][9], pole[4][10], pole[4][11], pole[4][12], pole[4][13], pole[4][14], pole[4][15]
, pole[5][0], pole[5][1], pole[5][2], pole[5][3], pole[5][4], pole[5][5], pole[5][6], pole[5][7], pole[5][8], pole[5][9], pole[5][10], pole[5][11], pole[5][12], pole[5][13], pole[5][14], pole[5][15]
, pole[6][0], pole[6][1], pole[6][2], pole[6][3], pole[6][4], pole[6][5], pole[6][6], pole[6][7], pole[6][8], pole[6][9], pole[6][10], pole[6][11], pole[6][12], pole[6][13], pole[6][14], pole[6][15]
, pole[7][0], pole[7][1], pole[7][2], pole[7][3], pole[7][4], pole[7][5], pole[7][6], pole[7][7], pole[7][8], pole[7][9], pole[7][10], pole[7][11], pole[7][12], pole[7][13], pole[7][14], pole[7][15]
, pole[8][0], pole[8][1], pole[8][2], pole[8][3], pole[8][4], pole[8][5], pole[8][6], pole[8][7], pole[8][8], pole[8][9], pole[8][10], pole[8][11], pole[8][12], pole[8][13], pole[8][14], pole[8][15]
, pole[9][0], pole[9][1], pole[9][2], pole[9][3], pole[9][4], pole[9][5], pole[9][6], pole[9][7], pole[9][8], pole[9][9], pole[9][10], pole[9][11], pole[9][12], pole[9][13], pole[9][14], pole[9][15]
, pole[10][0], pole[10][1], pole[10][2], pole[10][3], pole[10][4], pole[10][5], pole[10][6], pole[10][7], pole[10][8], pole[10][9], pole[10][10], pole[10][11], pole[10][12], pole[10][13], pole[10][14], pole[10][15]
, pole[11][0], pole[11][1], pole[11][2], pole[11][3], pole[11][4], pole[11][5], pole[11][6], pole[11][7], pole[11][8], pole[11][9], pole[11][10], pole[11][11], pole[11][12], pole[11][13], pole[11][14], pole[11][15]
, pole[12][0], pole[12][1], pole[12][2], pole[12][3], pole[12][4], pole[12][5], pole[12][6], pole[12][7], pole[12][8], pole[12][9], pole[12][10], pole[12][11], pole[12][12], pole[12][13], pole[12][14], pole[12][15]
, pole[13][0], pole[13][1], pole[13][2], pole[13][3], pole[13][4], pole[13][5], pole[13][6], pole[13][7], pole[13][8], pole[13][9], pole[13][10], pole[13][11], pole[13][12], pole[13][13], pole[13][14], pole[13][15]
, pole[14][0], pole[14][1], pole[14][2], pole[14][3], pole[14][4], pole[14][5], pole[14][6], pole[14][7], pole[14][8], pole[14][9], pole[14][10], pole[14][11], pole[14][12], pole[14][13], pole[14][14], pole[14][15]
, pole[15][0], pole[15][1], pole[15][2], pole[15][3], pole[15][4], pole[15][5], pole[15][6], pole[15][7], pole[15][8], pole[15][9], pole[15][10], pole[15][11], pole[15][12], pole[15][13], pole[15][14], pole[15][15]);


    }
    else
    {
        printf("Reseni neexistuje.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my naive code.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|             h | p   m   o     |     i   k     | n       f   l |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
| c   l   g   m | n           e | h   p         | o       d     |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
| o             |             d | b             |               |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|     p   i   e |     h       g |             m |         b     |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|     c         | h             | n   k       f |     i   g     |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|         h     |     l   p     | i   b   j     |         c     |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
| f   a         |     j   g     |             p |               |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|         e     |     i       o |         l     | h   p   n     |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| i       d     |         n     | o   a   g   b | l             |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|     f   j   g |         m     |     d   i     |             c |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
| l   k         |               | f             |             o |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|               |               |         m     | k           n |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|         n     | b       k     | g       o   d | c   h   i     |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|             o |             l |         n     | m             |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
| h   g       f |             j | p             |         e   d |
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +
|               | m   p       f |     c       j | b             |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And here is input data.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: From a first sight, it seems that you have too many nested `for` loops. Surely you can improve that, this question should be asked in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 1) use a one-dimentional board representation 2) use bitmasks for (un)usable letters per row/column/box

Comment: You mean to remember which letter was used before?

Comment: @user3177790: I think wildplasser means that you can mark cells as unusable for certain letters. For example, if you try `b` in (0, 0), you can rule out `b` for all cells in row 0, col 0 and 4x4-square (0, 0) in future trials. This can be done with bit-masks and will eliminate the calls to the costly function `isfree`. You must undo such markings after backtracking, of course, perhaps by making snap-shots of the board.

Comment: Actually if hexadoku has one result, then program is goin to show it (about 10s) but if not, then it stands in the loop i think.

Comment: @Brett Hale: the 4096 loop is not the hot spot here. `napln()` is called once from `main()`, but then calls itself recusively a few times, with 8,567,341 invocations total. Then, `isfree()` is called in a loop from `napln()`, with 137,076,218 invocations total. Then, there is a loop in `isfree()`, with 754,055,352 iterations in all.

Comment: @user3177790: instead of writing a solver yourself each time, there are very well writen *constraint-programming* libraries like *Gecode* where you simply specify the constraints and the solver uses propagation and branching to solve the problem itself.

Comment: @user3177790: BTW, not sure about your environment, but here when running on Linux compiled in -O3 with gcc on a five year old Phenom II processor, your original code runs in 2.5 seconds, not 10. Maybe just having a look at your compiler options could allow you to reach your target?

Comment: Just using CodeBlocks (gcc) on my W8.1 and including input through the powershell.

Comment: @user3177790: you mean you enter the input yourself?

Comment: @PhilippeAubertin - looks like my 'observation' was pretty lazy.

Comment: @BrettHale It wasn't obvious. I didn't see it myself, the code coverage tool told me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of always writing your own solver, you can use constraint-programming solvers like *Gecode* that are well written for these tasks.

```
#include <gecode/int.hh>
#include <gecode/minimodel.hh>
#include <gecode/search.hh>

using namespace Gecode;

class Hexadoka : public Space {
protected:
    IntVarArray l;
public:
    Hexadoka(int hexadoku[16][16]) : l(* this, 16*16, 0, 15) {
        Matrix<IntVarArgs> m(l,16,16);
        for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
            distinct(*this, m.row(i)); //all rows must contain distinct values
            distinct(*this, m.col(i)); //all columns must contain distinct values
            for (int j=0; j<16; j++) {
                if(hexadoku[i][j] != -1) {
                    rel(*this, m(j,i), IRT_EQ, hexadoku[i][j]); //set already known values
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<16; i += 4) {
            for (int j=0; j<16; j += 4) {
                distinct(*this, m.slice(i, i+4, j, j+4)); //all blocks must contain distinct values
            }
        }
        branch(* this, l, INT_VAR_SIZE_MIN(), INT_VAL_MIN()); //set a brancher
    }
    Hexadoka(bool share, Hexadoka& s) : Space(share, s) {
        l.update(* this, share, s.l);
    }
    virtual Space* copy(bool share) {
        return new Hexadoka(share,* this);
    }
    char vl (int i, int j) const {
        int ofs = 16*i+j;
        if(l[ofs].assigned()) {
            return 'a'+l[ofs].val();
        } else {
            return ' ';
        }
    }

    void print(void) const {
        printf(
        "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +   +\n"
        "| %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c | %c   %c   %c   %c |\n"
        "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n"

                    , vl(0,0), vl(0,1), vl(0,2), vl(0,3), vl(0,4), vl(0,5), vl(0,6), vl(0,7), vl(0,8), vl(0,9), vl(0,10), vl(0,11), vl(0,12), vl(0,13), vl(0,14), vl(0,15)
                            , vl(1,0), vl(1,1), vl(1,2), vl(1,3), vl(1,4), vl(1,5), vl(1,6), vl(1,7), vl(1,8), vl(1,9), vl(1,10), vl(1,11), vl(1,12), vl(1,13), vl(1,14), vl(1,15)
                            , vl(2,0), vl(2,1), vl(2,2), vl(2,3), vl(2,4), vl(2,5), vl(2,6), vl(2,7), vl(2,8), vl(2,9), vl(2,10), vl(2,11), vl(2,12), vl(2,13), vl(2,14), vl(2,15)
                            , vl(3,0), vl(3,1), vl(3,2), vl(3,3), vl(3,4), vl(3,5), vl(3,6), vl(3,7), vl(3,8), vl(3,9), vl(3,10), vl(3,11), vl(3,12), vl(3,13), vl(3,14), vl(3,15)
                            , vl(4,0), vl(4,1), vl(4,2), vl(4,3), vl(4,4), vl(4,5), vl(4,6), vl(4,7), vl(4,8), vl(4,9), vl(4,10), vl(4,11), vl(4,12), vl(4,13), vl(4,14), vl(4,15)
                            , vl(5,0), vl(5,1), vl(5,2), vl(5,3), vl(5,4), vl(5,5), vl(5,6), vl(5,7), vl(5,8), vl(5,9), vl(5,10), vl(5,11), vl(5,12), vl(5,13), vl(5,14), vl(5,15)
                            , vl(6,0), vl(6,1), vl(6,2), vl(6,3), vl(6,4), vl(6,5), vl(6,6), vl(6,7), vl(6,8), vl(6,9), vl(6,10), vl(6,11), vl(6,12), vl(6,13), vl(6,14), vl(6,15)
                            , vl(7,0), vl(7,1), vl(7,2), vl(7,3), vl(7,4), vl(7,5), vl(7,6), vl(7,7), vl(7,8), vl(7,9), vl(7,10), vl(7,11), vl(7,12), vl(7,13), vl(7,14), vl(7,15)
                            , vl(8,0), vl(8,1), vl(8,2), vl(8,3), vl(8,4), vl(8,5), vl(8,6), vl(8,7), vl(8,8), vl(8,9), vl(8,10), vl(8,11), vl(8,12), vl(8,13), vl(8,14), vl(8,15)
                            , vl(9,0), vl(9,1), vl(9,2), vl(9,3), vl(9,4), vl(9,5), vl(9,6), vl(9,7), vl(9,8), vl(9,9), vl(9,10), vl(9,11), vl(9,12), vl(9,13), vl(9,14), vl(9,15)
                            , vl(10,0), vl(10,1), vl(10,2), vl(10,3), vl(10,4), vl(10,5), vl(10,6), vl(10,7), vl(10,8), vl(10,9), vl(10,10), vl(10,11), vl(10,12), vl(10,13), vl(10,14), vl(10,15)
                            , vl(11,0), vl(11,1), vl(11,2), vl(11,3), vl(11,4), vl(11,5), vl(11,6), vl(11,7), vl(11,8), vl(11,9), vl(11,10), vl(11,11), vl(11,12), vl(11,13), vl(11,14), vl(11,15)
                            , vl(12,0), vl(12,1), vl(12,2), vl(12,3), vl(12,4), vl(12,5), vl(12,6), vl(12,7), vl(12,8), vl(12,9), vl(12,10), vl(12,11), vl(12,12), vl(12,13), vl(12,14), vl(12,15)
                            , vl(13,0), vl(13,1), vl(13,2), vl(13,3), vl(13,4), vl(13,5), vl(13,6), vl(13,7), vl(13,8), vl(13,9), vl(13,10), vl(13,11), vl(13,12), vl(13,13), vl(13,14), vl(13,15)
                            , vl(14,0), vl(14,1), vl(14,2), vl(14,3), vl(14,4), vl(14,5), vl(14,6), vl(14,7), vl(14,8), vl(14,9), vl(14,10), vl(14,11), vl(14,12), vl(14,13), vl(14,14), vl(14,15)
                            , vl(15,0), vl(15,1), vl(15,2), vl(15,3), vl(15,4), vl(15,5), vl(15,6), vl(15,7), vl(15,8), vl(15,9), vl(15,10), vl(15,11), vl(15,12), vl(15,13), vl(15,14), vl(15,15));
    }
};

int main () {
    char pole[17][17];
    char tmp[66];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, m = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

    printf("Zadejte hexadoku:\n");
    while ( scanf( " %[^\n]", &tmp ) == 1 ) {
        for ( j = 2; j <= 62; j += 4 ) {
            if ( tmp[0] != '+' ) {
                pole[i][k] = tmp[j];
                k++;
            }
        }
        pole[i][k] = '\0';
        k = 0;
        if ( tmp[0] != '+' )
            i++;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) {
        for ( l = 0; l < 16; l++ ) {
            if( !(( pole[i][l] >='a' && pole[i][l] <= 'p' ) || ( pole[i][l] == ' ' )) ) { printf("Nespravny vstup.\n"); return 1; }
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    l = 0;
    for (m = 0; m < 16; m++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            for (l = 0; l < 16; l++) {
                if ((pole[m][l] == pole[m][i]) && (i != l) && (pole[m][l] != ' ') && (pole[m][i] != ' ') ) { printf("Nespravny vstup.\n"); return 1; }
                if ((pole[l][m] == pole[i][m]) && (i != l) && (pole[l][m] != ' ') && (pole[i][m] != ' ') ) { printf("Nespravny vstup.\n"); return 1; }
            }
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    l = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (l = 0; l < 16; l+=3) {
        for (i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    for (y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
                        if(i==x && j==y) continue;
                        if ( (pole[i][j] == pole[x][y]) && (pole[i][j] != ' ') && (pole[x][y] != ' ') ) { printf("Nespravny vstup.\n"); return 1; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        i+=3;
        j+=3;
        x+=3;
        y+=3;
    }

    int hexadoku[16][16];
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            if(pole[i][j] == ' ') {
                hexadoku[i][j] = -1;
            } else {
                hexadoku[i][j] = (int) (pole[i][j]-'a');
            }
        }
    }
    Hexadoka* h = new Hexadoka(hexadoku); //initialize problem
    DFS<Hexadoka> e(h); //depth first search
    delete h;
    while (Hexadoka* s = e.next()) { //iterate over solutions
        s->print(); delete s; //print the solution
    }
}
```

Gecode uses propagators for (very) fast propagation and branchers in case a decision **must** be made. In case there are multiple solutions, all solutions are printed.

I've took the liberty to rewrite some small parts of your code, like for instance the parsing function:

```
if(pole[i][j] == ' ') {
    hexadoku[i][j] = -1;
} else {
    hexadoku[i][j] = (int) (pole[i][j]-'a');
}
```

`-1` is used to denote an unknown value. Otherwise conversions using ASCII are used.

When using `perf` to benchmark the program (including I/O), it takes the solver:

```
 Performance counter stats for './Hexadoka':

         10.646271 task-clock (msec)         #    0.921 CPUs utilized          
                70 context-switches          #    0.007 M/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
             1,806 page-faults               #    0.170 M/sec                  
        13,366,054 cycles                    #    1.255 GHz                     [39.33%]
         8,786,841 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   65.74% frontend cycles idle   
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
        15,827,908 instructions              #    1.18  insns per cycle        
                                             #    0.56  stalled cycles per insn
         3,186,179 branches                  #  299.277 M/sec                  
            78,708 branch-misses             #    2.47% of all branches        
   <not supported> L1-dcache-loads:HG      
           465,134 L1-dcache-load-misses:HG  #    0.00% of all L1-dcache hits   [63.40%]
            99,919 LLC-loads:HG              #    9.385 M/sec                   [26.66%]
   <not supported> LLC-load-misses:HG      

       0.011555631 seconds time elapsed
```

so less than `0.02` seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you want to hear :), but the best way to speed up this program (as is most often the case) is to profile it to identify where most of the time is spent, then focus on these spots.

You have deeply nested loops, and a function that calls itself recursively in a loop. These are all good potential candidates where a seemingly small change can make a big difference. The one you should start with is not obvious (at least to me), but the profiling tool will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Sudoku is so-called NP-complete, which means that no logic can exist to construct a solution. The only method is to try, and backtrack when it fails. This is an exhausitve search for a solution and is I believe O(n^2).

When a problem-type is NP-complete it also means that no procedure can exist that can tell you how many solutions there are. You just must test all posibilities and see if it is a solution, and continue until you have tried all possibilities. Only then do you know how many solutions the puzzle has.

There are ways to speed up the process - these are heuristic methods. For example, you can have in each cell a set of values that can still be valid. Such a value is then not used as a [candidate] in the row or column. Now only the values in this set need to be checked, not all values.

So indeed, speed-up the code, or use heuristics.

Comment: Your answer is quite *sloppy*: first of all you claim there is no procedure to tell how many solutions there are: well a simple procedure is enumerating the solutions. Secondly most puzzles you see in newspapers never require one to branch. And furthermore there exists very efficient solvers, that are capable of solving simple puzzles like the Sudoku puzzle in milliseconds.

Comment: The point with NP is not how many milliseconds it takes, but that it has been PROVEN there is no procedure more efficient than exhaustive search (trial-and-error), where heuristics at best can 'cut the corners'. Solvers are also heuristic, even if each heurstic method has a solid mathematical framework. As there is no other procedure to find a soluton than exhaustive search, there can be no procedure other than exhaustice search (which is enumeration) to tell you the number of solutions. Please consult you NP text book.

Comment: There is no proof at all. That's the P versus NP problem, otherwise [citation needed]. Although many researchers belief P != NP, it is not proven and some famous computer scientists like Donald Knuth even belief P=NP. What I mean is that your answer is *sloppy*: It states "it also means that no procedure can exist that can tell you how many solutions there are." in one sentence, then you actually make a statement that conflicts with it: you can perform enumeration. In other words you should say: *"There is currently only one way to count the number of solutions: enumerate the search space"*.

Comment: You are right @CommuSoft4. I'll try to be more precise in my statements.